# How do I apply the first partial function that works in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a list `fns` of partial functions from `a` to `b`, which I represent as functions from `a` to `Maybe b`, and I have an object `x` of type `a`. Suppose now that I want to define another function from `a` to `Maybe b` which takes the value of the first `f x` that is not `Nothing`, if such an `f` exists in `fns`, or the value `Nothing` if no such `f` exists. So basically it outputs `f x` for the first `f` that works, or `Nothing` if no `f` works.

It isn't hard to come up with some code that does the job. For example, one can create a list `[f x| f <- fns]` remove all the `Nothing`s from it, and then take the head of the resulting list, or `Nothing` if that list is empty. But that feels clumsy, and this seems like the kind of general situation for which there is a much more stylish implementation using some built-in function in Haskell. If so, then I'd be interested to know what it is.

Answer (score 12):

This is what [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) is for. It represents choice and here you are choosing between `Maybe` values. You can do something like

```
foldr (<|>) empty [f x | f <- fns]
```

In `Data.Foldable` you also have [`asum :: (Foldable t, Alternative f) => t (f a) -> f a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:asum) which does what you want even more directly:

```
asum [f x | f <- fns]
```

---

As a side remark, I should note that [`MonadPlus`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus) also does what you want for its `Maybe` instance. As in the above, you can have

```
foldr mplus mempty [f x | f <- fns]
```

And

```
msum [f x | f <- fns]
```

But IMO you should use `Alternative` here since that more accurately conveys your meaning of "choice".

Comment: `asum` is in base, in `Data.Foldable`.

Comment: Using [`Star`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.2/docs/Data-Profunctor.html#t:Star) from the profunctors package, you can also write `runStar . asum . fmap Star`, thanks to the `Alternative f => Alternative (Star f a)` instance.

Comment: @danidiaz Yeah, I realized that a couple of minutes ago - I was thrown off because I was looking for `asum` in `Control.Applicative` where `Alternative` is defined. And that is a neat trick with `Star`! I've been looking for something like `Star`...

Comment: Rather than that list comprehension, I think `map ($ x) fns` is nicer.

Comment: @amalloy Or, ahem, `sequenceA fns x` thanks to the function ("Reader") applicative.

Comment: @amalloy I see no point in using `map`. If you want to make it clear that you are working on a list, a list comprehension does that better. If you want to write polymorphic code, use `fmap` instead. Also, why not `($ x) <$> fns` while we are at it... ;)

Comment: I did consider `($ x) <$> fns` but I think the use of `$`-based operators to do two different things will look more confusing to someone who's not familiar with what's going on.

Answer (score 9):

In `Data.Monoid`, a `newtype` copy of `Maybe`, called `First`, has the "take the first `Just`" behaviour.

If you were looking for a function of type

```
[a -> First b] -> a -> First b
```

with the behaviour you describe, it would simply be

```
fold
```

from `Data.Foldable`, because the monoid behaviour for `a ->` does the pointwise lifting needed: the `Monoid` for `a -> First b` is exactly picking the first application outcome whic works. Sadly (for my tears over this have been many), to get `Maybe` instead of `First` takes a little more work.

Note that the pointwise lifting, yanking `a ->` out through `[]`, is just the sort of job for `sequenceA`, so

```
(asum .) . sequenceA
```

will do the job.

It's good to get the monoid structure you need cued from the type: in this case, accessing the `Alternative` behaviour with `asum` will have to do.

Comment: Do you know whether there are plans to get `Semigroup` into `base`, so that we can relax `Monoid (Maybe a)`'s superclass constraint and have an instance which doesn't reduce grown men to tears?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson You might like [this](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/Libraries/Proposals/SemigroupMonoid).

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, it's in `base`, and will be a superclass of `Monoid`, but that's not what so disturbs pigworker. He wants `First` semantics for `Foldable Maybe` and can't get them.

Comment: dfeuer is correct about what I want in this case. Making "lifted `Semigroup`" the `Monoid` for `Maybe` would not fix the above problem. I think there should be a whole other type for lifting a `Semigroup`: its raw data representation might be the same as for `Maybe`, but the type class mechanism's way of grabbing useful apparatus for us means that in Haskell, when we name a type, we are not only naming the data representation but also the implicitly associated structure. `Maybe` is for failure propagation and recovery. Something else should lift `Semigroup`, and have that `Monoid` instance.

Comment: I meant the `Monoid` instance, of course. Sorry if I confused anyone.

Answer (score 4):

*Warning:* This is a really non-standard solution. But I personally really like it for its elegance - and the underlying mind-bending.

On https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree you can find a function named `swing`. Its implementation and type are confusing at first:

```haskell
swing :: (((a -> b) -> b) -> c -> d) -> c -> a -> d
swing = flip . (. flip id)
```

You can get a first idea of what it does when you see its fully applied form:

```haskell
swing f c a = f ($ a) c
```

In conjunction with other higher-order functions it does things that almost look like magic. Examples from the link:

```haskell
swing map       :: [a -> b] -> a -> [b]
swing any       :: [a -> Bool] -> a -> Bool
swing foldr     :: b -> a -> [a -> b -> b] -> b
swing zipWith   :: [a -> b -> c] -> a -> [b] -> [c]
swing find      :: [a -> Bool] -> a -> Maybe (a -> Bool)
swing partition :: [a -> Bool] -> a -> ([a -> Bool], [a -> Bool])
```

All these functions do exactly what you would assume from the types. (But note that the wiki is a little out of date. By now, most of these functions automatically work for any `Foldable` type.)

The function that you search could start from

```haskell
swing mapMaybe :: [a -> Maybe b] -> a -> [b]
```

and then apply `listToMaybe`. (Both functions are from `Data.Maybe`)

A more general form would be

```haskell
swing mapM :: (Monad m, Traversable t) => t (a -> m b) -> a -> m (t b)
```

so for example (using the `ClassyPrelude` for full generality at the cost of some constraint noise, with `headMay` as a more general form of `listToMaybe`):

```haskell
f :: (Traversable t, MonoFoldable (t b), Element (t b) ~ b)
  => t (a -> Maybe b) -> a -> Maybe b
f functions x = join $ headMay <$> swing mapM functions x
```

Yes, it might turn your head into mush - but it's like bending your head to see a smiley, only with your whole mind.